# R Shiny - Using shinyjs::toggleState with shinyWidgets::pickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

The app below contains a radio button group labelled `Options` and a renderUI expression that renders:

1. an input element `input$data` which depends on the value of the
   selected button and
2. an actionButton `input$add`.

I would like to disable the button until the user selects a valid value for `input$data`. I tied `observe({ toggleState(id = 'add', condition = !is.null(input$data)) })` but this fails. Printing the value of `input$data` to the console shows that the pickerInput initializes with two separate values `NULL` and `""`:

```
NULL
[1] ""
```

and so `!is.null(input$data)` returns:

```
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```

Instead of just `FALSE`.

The app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

                prettyRadioButtons('opt', label = 'Options', choices = c('state', 'file', 'letters')),

                uiOutput('upload')

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$upload = renderUI({

    tagList(
      switch(input$opt, 
           'state' = pickerInput('data', 'Choose a state', 
                                 choices = state.name, 
                                 options = list(title = "States..."),
                                 choicesOpt = list(subtext = seq_along(state.name))
                                 ), 

           'file' = fileInput('data', 'Select file'), 

           'letters' = pickerInput('data', 'Choose a letter', 
                                   choices = LETTERS, 
                                   options = list(title = "Letters..."),
                                   choicesOpt = list(subtext = seq_along(LETTERS))
                                   )
           ), 

      actionButton('add', 'Add')

      )

  })

  observe({

    print(input$data) # pickerInput initializes with two values
    toggleState(id = 'add', condition = !is.null(input$data))

  })


})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also, when you switch the radio button from the default selection of `state` to `file` and then back to `state`, the pickerInput returns just `[1] ""` (not the

```
NULL
[1] ""
```

that it returns on startup). I'm not sure what's going on here and I couldn't find anything relating to this in the documentation for pickerInput so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty string `''` isn't a null object in R

`?is.null`

> NULL represents the null object in R: it is a reserved word.
>   NULL is often returned by expressions and functions whose values are
>   undefined.

```
> !is.null('')
[1] TRUE
```

However `shiny::isTruthy` will solve this

```
> isTruthy('')
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew the difference between `NULL` and `""` but `isTruthy()` is new to me.